# How can i make django-rest-framework-jwt return token on registration?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-registration, django-rest-auth

I have a basic django rest service, which

1. registers a person and
2. updates his password.

I want to add jwt authentication on top of it. If I follow the tutorial I would need to add a new url named "api-token-auth" in project's urls.py. But, I don't want to add this new url and want my register call to send a token in response.

Here's my code:

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password')
        lookup_field = 'username'
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.exclude(is_superuser=1)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

1. What should be done to achieve this ? should I call api-auth-token inside my serializer's create method ?
2. How does django-rest-framework-jwt handles multiple authentication tokens and correctly identifies which token belongs to which user ? Especially when it doesn't store tokens in a db.
3. How can I use this authentication mechanism to limit my user to view/update/delete only his user ?
4. How can I use this authentication mechanism to do anything in general. For instance if a user wants to write his name to /tmp/abcd.txt. How can I make sure that only authenticated users would be able to do so ?
5. Are there any potential loopholes in this approach. Should I use the same code if my app is going to store lots of classified data ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Question 1*: To generate tokens manually on registration you can define and make use of a method like this:

```
import jwt
from rest_framework_jwt.utils import jwt_payload_handler

def create_token(user):
    payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
    token = jwt.encode(payload, settings.SECRET_KEY)
    return token.decode('unicode_escape')
```

you can add this method to the view and generate the token once the user has been registered and return it in the response.

*Question 2*: JWT tokens do not need to be stored in the database. You can read more about how JWT works at http://jwt.io/.

*Question 3 and 4*: To use tokens to limit access to a specific view, especially an APIView or one of its subclasses or a view provided by Django Rest framework, you need to specify the [permission classes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/). for example:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

*Question 5*: One potential loophole while working with Django Rest Framework is the default permissions that you setup from the settings of your application; if for example you `AllowAny` in the settings it'll make all the views publicly accessible unless you specifically override the permission classes in each view.

Answer (score 8):

The Accepted answer has some code that generates token but it doesn't show how to integrate it in serializer/view. Also not sure that manual `jwt.encode` is a good modern way of doing this if we already have `jwt_encode_handler`
to do this. You can create `SerializerMethodField` and create tokens there:

```
token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_token(self, obj):
    jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
    jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

    payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
    token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
    return token
```

Then add `token` field to `Meta.fields`.

[Working Example](https://maketips.net/tip/184/make-jwt-token-on-registration-with-drf)

Comment: What about refresh token ?