# How can i return json web token after creating user in djoser with dango rest framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, djoser

This is my serializer file for updating the default UserCreateSerializer of djoser.

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer as BaseUserSerializer

class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    # token = (What logic should i apply here to get the token of the user i am going to register.)
    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'token']
```

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598833/get-token-after-registration-with-djoser-django-rest-framework-jwt-and-django-r) but did'nt understand anything please help me to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer, \
UserSerializer as BaseUserSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_token')
    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'token']

    def get_token(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }
```